# Can you apply CSS only on text that is wrapped, i.e. the second and subsequent lines?

Tags: html, css, layout, word-wrap

I want to put a `margin-left` on only the text that is wrapped, i.e. text after the first line:

```
This is text with no margin left
     this text has margin left
```

Example

[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKLaK.png)

The input and the label are in 1 div and text is wrapped on the second line, which is what I want
but is it possible to have like a margin left on only the text that is wrapped on the second line

[jsfiddle example of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Kevin1990/UQ3A5)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yeah, sort of — I’d suggest combining `padding-left` and `text-indent`:

```css
.test {
    width:200px;
}

.test label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <label for="2question1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2question1" name="2question" title="Merknaam 1" /> Very long text which is wrapped on the next line
    </label><br>

    <label for="2question2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2question2" name="2question" title="Merknaam 2" /> Merknaam 2
    </label><br>

    <label for="2question3">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2question3" name="2question" title="Merknaam 3" /> Merknaam 3
    </label><br>

    <label for="2question4">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2question4" name="2question" title="Merknaam 4" /> Merknaam 4
    </label><br>
</div>
```

`text-indent` applies only to the first line of text in a block-level element, so it should achieve what you want.

See http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/qUvvv/

Comment: @Kevin: excellent, cheers. I’d suggest putting you `<input>`s inside your `<label>`s (this provides an unbroken click target as well), and use the `<label>`s to apply the outdent CSS. See http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/qUvvv/

Comment: headache savor ! thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, but you *can* apply CSS to the first line, so you could reverse your thinking to achieve the same effect.

Something like this:

```
.mytext {margin-left:-5em;}
.mytext:first-line {margin-left:0;}
```

Here's a JSFiddle example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/4ckxJ/3/

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstline.html for more info on the `:first-line` pseudo-class.

Comment: That doesn’t actually appear to work though — I think because each line doesn’t have its own individual box (in the CSS box model sense), it’s more like one continuous broken box.

Comment: eh, I had the wrong jsfiddle link! Updated to give you a *really* working version.

Comment: aha, there we go. Looks like you don’t actually need the `:first-line` bit in there though — if you remove it, it still works.

Comment: To provide proof for my comment (just three short years later): http://jsfiddle.net/4ckxJ/36/

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the line you want to wrap in a `span` and apply:

```
display: block;
margin-left: 12px;
```

Giving it `display: block` will make it wrap to a new line and the margin pushes it off to the right.

Comment: The text is dynamic so I don't know where the line will wrap

Answer (score 0):

as per your updated example, here's a [fork JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQ3A5/8/)

float the input and then make the label display block so it floats right in beside it - spacing created with padding and margin, `overflow:hidden` makes the text "not wrap"  - then you also might want to remove the `br`'s from your HTML