# asp.net webform Menu control how to indent wrapped items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms

I'm using a standard asp.net Menu control to display a menu on my page, and I have the text wrap option set to true.  What I'd like to do is indent the wrapped text as a visual clue that its part of the line above.

I followed this question: [Can you apply CSS only on text that is wrapped, i.e. the second and subsequent lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497112/can-you-apply-css-only-on-text-that-is-wrapped-i-e-the-second-and-subsequent-l)

but I can't see how to format the MenuItem elements within the Menu control.  Can this be referenced with CSS?

Not sure if this will help... but here is my html:

```
<asp:Menu ID="MSDSMenu" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="noPrint" ItemWrap="True">
     <Items>
          <asp:MenuItem Text="Search SDS" Value="Search MSDS" NavigateUrl="~/MSDS/SearchMSDS.aspx" />
          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MSDS/ByDept.aspx?dept=Shipping%25%27%20OR%20UsageDept%20LIKE%20%27%25Receiving"
                    Text="Shipping / Receiving" Value="Shipping / Recieving" />
          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MSDS/ByDept.aspx?dept=Other" Text="Other" Value="Other" />
     </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @jackncoke - Not sure what the code will help with here, standard control, just want guidance on how to format.

Answer (score 0):

There are several levels of styling on a menu:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server"
         CssClass="menuBar_style" >
            <LevelSubMenuStyles>
                <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="sub_style_top" />
                <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="sub_style_lvl1" />
            </LevelSubMenuStyles>

            <LevelMenuItemStyles>
                <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="item_style_top" />
                <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="item_style_lvl1" />
            </LevelMenuItemStyles>

            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem />
                <asp:MenuItem />
                <asp:MenuItem />
            </Items>

        </asp:Menu>
```

there's the css for the `Menu` itself, but then you can also define `LevelSubMenuStyles` and `LevelMenuItemStyles`, with separate style items within both of those for each level of your menu (in your case only the one level by the looks of it).

I reccommend trying to apply your wrapping to the `MenuItemStyle` css as this affects the actual control (i.e. the text usually), `SubMenuStyle` affects the container around the control I think.

Hope that makes sense... it's awfully confusing business, your best bet is to play around with the different tags for a while until you get a feel for them in your own head and hopefully you'll see what I mean.

*EDIT: I've just noticed this question is from two years ago! No idea how I ended up here, one minute I was browsing the latest questions and next... I'll leave the answer here in any case as menu styling has been a source of frustration for me in the past and this may help somebody else.*