# Hanging Indents on radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I have a list of radio buttons where I want any wrapped text to have a hanging indent similar to

```
o Location 1
o Location 2 xxx
  xxx xxx
```

I have tried using but this has no affect on the wrapped line.

```
text-indent: -0.8vw ;
padding-left: 0.8vw ;
```

Here is a simplified version of the code (the actual code is driven by data and is a longer list).

https://svelte.dev/repl/a373050bf11b43919b6e5c52795bea13?version=4.2.8

```css
.sideBar {
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

label {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.indented {
  /* text-indent: -0.8em ;
        padding-left: 0.8em ; */
}

.custom-radio {
  /* Hide the default radio button */
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.8em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #FFA500;
}

.custom-radio:checked {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  /* Change the background color when checked */
  border-color: #FFA500;
  /* Change the border color when checked */
}
```

```html
<div class="sideBar">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="custom-radio" name="locations" value=1 />
    <span class="indented">&nbsp; Location 1</span>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="custom-radio" name="locations" value=1 />
    <span class="indented">&nbsp; Location xxx xxx xxx</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would caution against using `&nbsp;` and `<br>` for spacing. Use margins instead; you get much more fine-grained control over how much space is created and it's using the language meant for styling (CSS) for styling, and the language meant for structure (HTML) for that purpose.

Secondly, this seems like a good use case for flexbox. Applying `display: flex` to the `label`, and allowing the `input` to neither grow nor shrink means it takes up its given `0.8em` of width and the `span` can take the remainder. I added margins to make up for the removed `&nbsp;`s and `<br>`s.

```css
.sideBar {
  width: 100px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

label {
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.indented {
  margin-left: 0.2em;
}

.custom-radio {
  /* Hide the default radio button */
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.8em;
  max-height: 0.8em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #FFA500;
  flex: 0 0 0.8em;
}

.custom-radio:checked {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  /* Change the background color when checked */
  border-color: #FFA500;
  /* Change the border color when checked */
}
```

```html
<div class="sideBar">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="custom-radio" name="locations" value=1 />
    <span class="indented">Location 1</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" class="custom-radio" name="locations" value=1 />
    <span class="indented">Location xxx xxx xxx</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Heretic Monkey.  Your answer is helpful, but my question as flagged a duplicate the first one here seems more straightforward. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369808/label-text-is-wrapped-but-not-indent-second-line